# Snippets not appearing on webpage

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am trying to build a snippet based the Wagtail tutorial [here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10/topics/snippets.html).

I have built my snippet in `models.py` and create a custom template tag in the `templatetags` folder and connected the snippet to a `Page` via `ForeignKey`. I have also created the html template and run both `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

The Snippet is a header image and a caption which appears on all pages except for the homepage. Code as follows:

Snippet Model:

```
@register_snippet
class HeroImage(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('text'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Snippet Custom Template Tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('hero_image.html', takes_context=True)
def hero_images(context):
    self = context.get('self')
    if self is None or self.depth <= 2:
        hero = ()
    else:
        hero = HeroImage.objects.all()
    return {
        'hero': hero,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

Snippet connected to Page:

```
class MenuPage(Page):
    hero = models.ForeignKey(
        'home.HeroImage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        SnippetChooserPanel('hero'),
    ]
```

I have created two Snippets and selected one in my Page in the admin interface. In the template I have tried many different calls to the Snippet but they all return nothing. Calls I have tried include:

```
{{ page.hero }}
{{ page.hero.text }}
{{ hero.text }}
{{ page.hero_images }}
{{ page.hero_images.text }}
Etc...
```

Nothing has worked unfortunately, the only thing I managed to get working is by typing `{{ hero }}` which returned `<QuerySet [<HeroImage: Lorem Ipsum One>, <HeroImage: Lorem Ipsum Two>]>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. In case anyone experiences something similar:

I had the template tags on a **separate** template which was being loaded into base.html. The template with the Snippet tags needs to be the **same** as the `Page` template.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio code, close VSC and then open it again